# Sort GridView Bound to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, datatable

I have a repository that contains all of my LINQ queries for this project that I am working on. I am able to get the LINQ results to a DataTable and bind that to a gridview for displaying the data. Now I need to make the gridview sortable. I have set `AllowSorting="true"` and I have the OnSort event handled in a routine in the codebehind. The program makes it into the sorting routine just fine.

Is manual sort my only option or is there an easier way to sort the gridview in the OnSort handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) example from MSDN and attaching my own datatable, which was acquired through a LINQ Query in my repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the GridView to a DataSourceControl then the sorting is taken care of for you. Otherwise you're stuck with doing it manually.