# Why my grid view doesn't sort with data table as a data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, sorting, gridview

Q:

Why my gridview doesn't do any thing when click on the column header to sort it:

My aspx:(in update panel)

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="gv_ActiveResearch" CssClass="datatable" AllowSorting="True"
                                                                runat="server" TabIndex="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5"
                                                                GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="gv_ActiveResearch_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="id"
                                                                OnPageIndexChanging="gv_ActiveResearch_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gv_ActiveResearch_RowCommand">
                                                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="center">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Size="16pt" Text="&#1604;&#1575; &#1610;&#1608;&#1580;&#1583; &#1576;&#1610;&#1575;&#1606;&#1575;&#1578;"></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                &nbsp;
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="م">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSerial" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="research_interest" HeaderText="research" SortExpression="research_interest">
                                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="edit">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/editpen.png"
                                                                                CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' CommandName="editResearch" />
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="delete">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/Symbols-Delete-icon.png"
                                                                                CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' CommandName="deleteResearch" />
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                </Columns>
                                                                <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="row" />
                                                            </asp:GridView>
```

My .cs:

```
protected void gv_ActiveResearch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                _activeResearchId = int.Parse(gv_ActiveResearch.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());
                hf_activeResearchId.Value = _activeResearchId.ToString();
                if (e.CommandName == "editResearch")
                {
                    lbl_activeResearchSerial.Text = ((Label)gv_ActiveResearch.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("lblSerial")).Text;
                    txt_activeResearch.Text = gv_ActiveResearch.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.TrimEnd();
                    Ibtn_saveResearch.Visible = true;
                    Session["add_research"] = 1;

                }
                else if (e.CommandName == "deleteResearch")
                {
                    cc1lectresearchDTO obj = new cc1lectresearchDTO();
                    obj.Id = _activeResearchId;
                    int result = cc1lectresearchDAL.Delete(obj);
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        CancelResearch();
                        BindGV_ActiveResearch();
                        this.ShowStatus("The operation has been executed successfully.", "Note", "", "true");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.ShowStatus("Wrong operation,Try again.", "Error", "error", "true");
                    }
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
                this.ShowStatus("Wrong operation,Try again.", "Error", "error", "true");
            }
        }
```

---

```
private void BindGV_ActiveResearch()
        {
            try
            {
                gv_ActiveResearch.DataSource = cc1lectresearchDAL.List(int.Parse(Session["emp_num"].ToString()));//this method returns data table..
                gv_ActiveResearch.DataBind(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to code the sort method.  There are lots of ways you could sort data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a datatable as your data source, it is easy to sort. Just use something like below and databind the grid again.

```
if (sortExpression != null && sortExpression.Length > 0) 
{
    table.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression + " " + sortOrder;
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240252/sort-gridview-bound-to-datatable) link.

Comment: where to write this ,and if i have three columns and i wanna to sort when click on each one how to do that.

Comment: Did you take a look at the link I mentioned? Check this.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx..  Basically you assign a sort expression to each column and have an event in the code behind to handle sorting. Check the sort expression and sort order in the event(as explained in the link above) , sort the datatable and bind the grid again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `SortExpression="ColumnName"` in all the columns that you need them to sort.

Comment: I did ,`SortExpression="research_interest"` look to `aspx`.