# Allow GridView Sorting ASP C#

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, datatable, datasource

I have a `GridView` that i fill using a `sqldatasource` i use the Header to sort with no problems at all by enabling `AllowSorting="true"`

Then i filter this `GridView` using different controllers, i run the filtering function using a `DataTable` as below:

```
    var mySqlConnection = //mySqlConnection
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SPRlist_GetSPRCombine", mySqlConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPRKaimrcNo", sprkaimrcno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPRNo", sprno);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfRequest", dateofrequest);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequesterBadge", requesterbadge);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", department);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPRStatus", sprstatus);
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
```

i call the function passing the controllers variables and it gives me back the exact result:

```
    GridViewSPRlist.DataSourceID = "";
    //Data Table Function Passing Controllers
    GridViewSPRlist.DataBind();
```

The problem is : if the `GridView` is filtered i can't sort it and i get the below error:

> The data source does not support sorting.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The data source does not support sorting.

How can i enable sorting the DataSource of a DataTable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort GridView Bound to DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240252/sort-gridview-bound-to-datatable)

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776372/allow-sorting-by-column-gridview

Comment: @TonyDong i already checked it and didn't work for me !

Comment: Did you add OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" on html gridview?

Comment: @TonyDong yes i did, actually even the sorting that was working in the sqldatasource didn't work after i used the function in the link you mentioned

Comment: you have to remove sqldatasource, and use page_load to bind gridview first

Comment: @TonyDong that's exactly what i'm doing i have the gridview bind to the sqldatasource when first the page is loaded, NOT in the gridview html tag

Comment: Could you do debug and see the Date Table get sorted and grid view did not bind more than one time after click column sort?

Comment: @TonyDong this is the scenario: once page is loaded the grid is binded from the sqldatasource i can sort with no problem, once i try to filter i get an error that the datasource(datatable) doesn't allow sorting!

Comment: Please use DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);, data view allow sorting

Answer (score 0):

Sort the DataTable itself in code behind and bind it to the GridView. Maybe that is a solution for your problem?

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "sortExpression DESC";
//use DefaultView.ToTable() if you want to use the sorted datatable later on in a viewstate or session etc.
//dt.DefaultView.ToTable();

GridViewSPRlist.DataSource = dt;
GridViewSPRlist.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after merging all the solutions I've found.
I removed the `sqldatasource` on load and replaced it with the same `DataTable`passing null arguments to the function to retreive the whole data set

Functions for sorting (Don't forget to call it on your `GridView` OnSorting):

```
protected void GridViewSPRlist_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

    if (dt != null)
    {
        //Sort the data.
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + (GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression));
        GridViewSPRlist.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];

        GridViewSPRlist.DataBind();
    }
}

private string GetSortDirection(string column)
{

    // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
    string sortDirection = "ASC";

    // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
    string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

    if (sortExpression != null)
    {
        // Check if the same column is being sorted.
        // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
        if (sortExpression == column)
        {
            string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
            if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
            {
                sortDirection = "DESC";
            }
        }
    }

    // Save new values in ViewState.
    ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
    ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

    return sortDirection;
}
```

`DataTable`Function:

```
public DataTable GetSPRCombine(//Your Param)
{
    var mySqlConnection = //Your Connection String
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SPRlist_GetSPRCombine", mySqlConnection);
        //Your command parameters
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
    }
```